# can User profile synchronization be started from a web service?

Tags: development, web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

I'm trying to kick off the user profile syc using a web service. Here is what i've tried :

```
[WebMethod]
        public string runUserProfileService()
        {
            var message = "";

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://servernamehere/"))
            {
                site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                UserProfileConfigManager upcm = new UserProfileConfigManager(context);

                if (!upcm.IsSynchronizationRunning())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        upcm.StartSynchronization();
                        message = "running";
                        return message;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        message = ex.Message;
                        return message;
                    }
                }

                message = "running";
            }

            return message;
        }
```

Here is the exception that I continue to get:

> The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your
>   Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
Context.Items["FormDigestValidated"] = true;
SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();
```

to the beginning of your method.

Edit:

Revised code above.

Comment: I added this to the top of the method. When it hits this line I get the same error as before.

Comment: How are you calling the webservice?  Is it through a http get?

Comment: Ok, I changed the code in my answer.  Try adding that at the top.